# Is there a Turing machine that packs a machine and its input into a single machine?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

Let $U$ be the universal Turing machine. Is there a Turing machine $T$ taking two inputs such that $\forall m \forall n \exists q \; T(m; n) = q \land U(q;0)=U(m;n)$?

It seems "obvious" that there is such a Turing machine, but if there is one, then the function $Q(n) = 1 + T(n;n)$ is not computable because it's the diagonal of $T$ plus one (it is not in the list of all computable function) so there is no TM that computes $Q$ so there can't be any TM $T$ either.

This is the same argument for non-computability of Halting Problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: Keep in mind that the functions involved will be *partial*.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't think it matters because I can imagine a compiler from python to TM and in python it is easy to convert a 'def f(n): ...' to 'def f(): n = number ...'

Comment: The problem here is not the packing of the machine and input into a single machine - it's the recursive evaluation

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of whatever notation is used by the OP, I will use the following notation: $T^k$ is the $k$-th Turing machine under an acceptable numbering of Turing machine, and $T^k(n)$ is the result of running the $k$-th Turing machine on onput $n$. The output is either undefined, if $T^k$ never terminates on input $n$, or is a number.

The function $Q(n) = 1 + T^n(n)$ is computable. What you are missing is the fact that in general Turing machines compute *partial* functions.

Let us see how your imagined diagonalization argument for $Q$ fails. We want to show, for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, that the $k$-th Turing machine does not compute $Q$, i.e., that $Q \neq T^k$, by arguing that if $Q = T^k$ then
$$T^k(k) = Q(k) = 1 + T^k(k).$$
Now this would be a contradiction if we knew that $T^k(k)$ is a natural number. But $T^k(k)$ may be undefined, in which case there is no contradiction because both sides of the equation are undefined. The diagonalization proof breaks down.

Comment: I think you need to explain your notation further. What is $T(m; n)$ then? In any case, even with confusing notation you should be able to understand the gist of what several people have said now: you cannot diagonalize against partial computable functions, as the diagonal simply isn't defined everywhere.

Comment: By the way, at my department we have rather successfully used Enderton's [Computability theory](https://www.elsevier.com/books/computability-theory/enderton/978-0-12-387835-9) textbook. I can recommend it as a good first textbook on the topic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139946/discussion-on-answer-by-andrej-bauer-is-there-a-turing-machine-that-packs-a-mach).

Comment: Indeed it seems clear that a reasonable implementation of Q would descend into some form of infinite recursion when trying to evaluate this as Q(k) = 1+Tk(k) = 1+Q(k) = 1+[1+Tk(k)] = 1+[1+Q(k)] = 1+[1+[1+Tk(k)]] = ...